# RPI is rebooting every time I plug in the wireless device?

Tags: raspbian, wireless, power-supply, archlinux

I encounter a very annoying problem with My Raspberry Pi which is rebooting whenever I plug into it a Wireless USB adapter or an ethernet adapter.

Comment: Sounds like a power issue, how are you powering the Pi? Are you plugging the WiFi adapter into the Pi or a powered hub?

Comment: My PSU is 5v 0.7 A I think  the problem comes from the polyfuses and the dongle is connected to the pi

Comment: if I use both the GPIO connector and the micro usb does this double the Amper value and the voltage value or only the amper value ?

Comment: DO NOT connect power to both the mini-USB and the GPIO as this may damage your device and/or Power Supply! However, according to [this](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=10500) you can skip the polyfuse by supplying power via the gpio.

Comment: the problem is the power that the laptop is delivering
5v / 0.7 A

Comment: Again, I can only suggest getting a powered USB hub ([this](https://www.modmypi.com/7-port-raspberry-pi-hub-eu?filter_name=usb%20hub) for example) which you can plug into a wall outlet. you can also power your RPi from the hub, as the power supply is short-circuit-proof.

Answer (score 2):

As you can read [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Hardware#Power), 700mA is barely enough to run the B Model - I'm using a 1.2A Power supply and this still happens sometimes (using Model B Rev. 2) , I'd suggest getting a powered hub, then you won't have to worry about what you plug in/out.

edit: the polyfuses you talked about in the comment have been removed in Model Revision 2. Are you using a Rev 1 board?

edit 2:
Oh, and overclocking the Pi will use more power - so if you did that, try going back to the standard level.

Comment: I'm talking about the C32 fuse !!

Comment: He should also upgrade the PSU he is using to power the Pi as well, as you point out it is barely up to the job.

Comment: if there is a problem with the PSU tell me why it is working fine after the reboot ?

Comment: there always is the question of what you want out of your RPi. As any other Computer, the RPi does not have a stable power consumption, it depends on what you do with it. Being idle will take much less power than calculating the n-th fibonacci number. So, while the RPi _works_ with your power supply, it is not guaranteed that it will not fail when more power is needed (also, when the RPi heats up, resistance will rise). If you're fine taking the chance, please do so, but this is the reason I suggest switching PSU.

Comment: what is the best values for Power supply ?

Comment: Farnell recommends the following power supplies:

    Model A: 5V dc, 500-700mA
    Model B: 5V dc, 700-1500mA - 
if you want to attach usb devices directly/without powered hub, always go for the high end! in fact, I'd always always go for the high end :D