# RPI with GPIO connector AND micro usb Power supply?

Tags: gpio, debian, usb-power, rpi.gpio

if I use both the GPIO connector and the micro usb does this double the Amper value and the voltage value or only the amper value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Adafruit Industries](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/connect-the-lead), you should never connect both the GPIO and the USB Power supply.
(as seen as a comment [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15306/rpi-is-rebooting-every-time-i-plug-in-the-wireless-device))